# multiple conditions in IF statement on excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am stuck in this part in excel.

[image: HERE IS MY EXCEL SHEET]

As you see in this picture, i did a formula that says if the student pays all the balance and the remain number is **0** it will write **Paid** in the balance column

But if nobody registered any course and the balance also will be **0** it also shows that is **paid**

So i want to specify if a student registered and paid all, the balance column will write **paid** and if nobody registered, the balance column will be **empty** and if for example a student pay half of the money the remain balance will be shown in the balance column

This is the formula i am using in the balance column

**=IF((L7-H7-I7-J7-K7)=0,"Paid",L7-H7-I7-J7-K7)**

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCX80.png)

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and include all relevant information.

Comment: Just use any of your columns that will be blank to check if someone is registered `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E7)), *your current formula here*, "")`

Comment: You might also want to look into the [and function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) & [or function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0)